# Precision of sliders in WebMathematica

Tags: manipulate, precision-and-accuracy, webmathematica, slider

I have been developing a `Manipulate` plot to put on the web. One of my parameters varies over a small interval, `{{D32, 2.38*10^-3, "D32"}, 0.001227, 0.0049108}.` This is not an issue if I embed my code as a CDF, but I am also hoping to post it with WebMathematica. WebMathematica shows `D32` to be `0.00` and does not allow the user to adjust the toggle bar. I have tried `` {{D32, 2.38*10^-3, "D32"}, 0.001227`15, 0.0049108`15} ``, but am not sure what to do from there. Does anyone have any thoughts, or is webMathemtica's kernel simply reaching a limit of precision on this calculation.